# why a citric fruit rind is cooked several times to make a marmalade

Tags: jam, marmalade

why the citric fruit rind is cooked several times to make a marmalade? i meaning boiled several times, its to reduce acidity or bitterness or what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Speaking from a different dish: when I make citrus caramel I have to [blanch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blanching_(cooking)) the citrus peels a few times (three times mostly). It greatly reduces bitterness from the white part of the skin.

[Here's](https://sweets.seriouseats.com/2011/06/sweet-technique-how-to-candy-citrus-zest-garnish-citrus-peel.html) Kenji-Lopez Alt's take on it.